# Swapping Values Using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have looked up reflections in java, but still don't quite understand them. I need to "swap" values of two local parameters using a reflection. Here is what I have. I know it doesn't swap the values which is why I need to use the reflection. How do I do this?

```
public class SwapBla {
static int x = 1;
static int y = 2;
 public static void swap2(int x, int y)
 {
   int temp = x;
   x = y;
   y = temp;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think reflection could solve this problem?

Comment: I was told that it would solve the problem by a peer, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Should've asked them. Also, I don't see why you have the `static` fields in your sample.

Comment: If you're just trying to flip ints, and need to do it a lot, it may be faster/more memory efficient to use `x ^= y; y ^= x; x ^= y;`  I feel something similar should be able to be used on object references, just not sure how difficult access to the references binary would be

Comment: I did and they didn't give me a clear answer. I only gave a small portion of my overall code, later I have a main method that prints out the values from the methods.

Comment: Reflection does not allow you to operate on local variables. And, regardless, Java is pass-by-value.

Comment: So then how do I swap the values of the parameters?

Comment: As you're doing it right now. That swaps the values of the parameters. What you can't do is swap the values of the arguments provided when invoking the method.

Comment: I want it to swap the values of the parameters, if x=1 and y=2
when i run the code, they don't swap. x still = 1 as y still =2.